# scroll to an element using js failed in my case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: highlightedBlock is not defined`

```
$(this).parents('.type-coupon').addClass('highlightedBlock');

            function findPos(obj) {
                    var curtop = 0;
                    if (obj.offsetParent) {
                        do {
                            curtop += obj.offsetTop;
                        } while (obj = obj.offsetParent);
                    return [curtop];
                    }
                }

            //Scroll to location of highlightedBlock on load
            window.scroll(0,findPos(highlightedBlock));
```

says above block is within an event, how can I ensure `highlightedBlock` is defined? findPos function is to scroll the window's screen to an element, but I can't hardcode highlightedBlock class. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot You check whether any class of that sort exists or not .. eg:-

```
if($('.'+className).length >0)
{
 window.scroll(0,findPos(className));
}
```

I hope i got your problem ...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a local variable and attempt to assign the value of your `highlightedBlock` to it, falling back to `false` for when the variable does not exist:

```
var highlightedBlock = highlightedBlock || false;
```

You can then pass this into an `if` statement prior to making your call:

```
if (highlightedBlock)
    window.scroll(0,findPos(highlightedBlock));
```

Comment: it doesn't work, i tried. I think it's because the findPos run at the same time with the addClass.